# error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'Edge' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'?

Tags: c++

Hi...

```
    #ifndef Node_H
    #define Node_H
    #include <vector>
    #include <stack>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Edge.h"
    #include "CongestionMap.h"
    using namespace std;   
    class Node
    {

    public:
        Node(){ visit = false;};
    Node(int id);
    ~Node(); 
    int getID();
    void setLocation(int &row, int &col, GridCell *Gc);;
    void displayList();

    private:
        int row;
        int col;
        int id;
        bool visit;
        int parrent;
        int distance;
        typedef vector<  Edge > adjNodeList;

    };
    #endif
```

When i compile the project i get error as 
project\node.h(43): error C2065: 'Edge' : undeclared identifier
project\project\node.h(43): error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'Edge' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'...
    please help me ...
Edge.h

```
#ifndef Edge_H
#define Edge_H
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

class Edge
{
public:
    Edge() {};
Edge(Node *firstNode, Node *secNode, int inCost);
~Edge(void);

Node* getDstNode();
Node* getOrgNode();
int   getCost();

private:
Node *orgNode;
Node *dstNode;
int cost;

};
#endif
```

Comment: You don't specify the contents of `edge.h`. There's probably some circular `#include` going on.

Comment: You seem to have a circular reference between Edge.h and Node.h . Try forward declaring Node class in Edge.h

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As some commenters have noted, you have circular references.  The code is parsed in the order it appears.

If we start in `node.h`, early on, it includes `edge.h`.

`edge.h` includes `node.h`, but that cleverly won't do anything because of the `#ifdef` protection, and the redundant `#pragma once` (they both achieve the same thing, so you might consider sticking to just one approach).

Ok, the first class definition we would encounter is that for `Edge`.  Great, except that it refers to `Node`, and nobody knows what that is...because we're still in the code for `edge.h` that's been included into `node.h`.

Likely you have things happening the other way around and `edge.h` is being included first.  The next thing that happens is that `node.h` is included, and it declares `Node`, which expects to know what `Edge` is, but nobody has seen that yet.

So you'll need to use [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), that is in `edge.h` before you declare `class Edge`, add a line indicating what `Node` is:

```
class Node;
```

and conversely in `node.h`, provide a forward declaration for `Edge`.  The second one is to cover the case where somebody includes `node.h` before they include `edge.h`.

As an example, if you had them both declared in the same file you would still need to do something like:

```
class Node;  // forward declaration so that compiler knows that 
             // Node is a class when it gets to parsing Edge

class Edge {
...
private:
    Node *orgNode;
};

class Node {

....
};
}
```